# Camera Remote API for Sony a7II 'not available now'

Tags: api, camera, sony

Let me start by giving some context: I have a Sony a7II camera which I wanted to control remotely. There's an app for that (PlayMemories) but it doesn't have all the features I need. So I decided to write my own app using Camera Remote API.

What I achieved so far: I have established connection between camera and phone, I have a working liveview and I'm displaying current aperture value on screen ('currentFNumber' from getEvent response).

What I'm trying to do: change aperture value. Calling getMethodTypes returns setFNumber as supported for my camera model. And here's the problem. It's on the supported list but not on the currently available list.

ShootMode is set to "still" and camera status is "IDLE" but when I check for 'setFNumber' availability it says 'currently not available'.

Answers for similar questions on stackoverflow suggested changing CameraFunction to 'remote shooting' but for me it's unavailable (error 12 'No such method'). When I check currentCameraFunction it's giving me null.
StartRecMode doesn't seem to be required (there's only 'stopRecMode' in currently available API calls).

So here's my question: am I missing something else or is it possible my camera software is faulty? I'm kinda stuck with this problem for a while now and I'd really appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things to check here:

1. Check that your camera has the latest firmware.  http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=ILCE7M2&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab
2. Check that you have the latest Smart Remote Control app installed on your camera - https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=is9104-npia09014_00-f00002

Comment: Yes, thank you for a quick answer. The problem was with Smart Remote Control app on the camera. I've updated it and now even the PlayMemories app has more features.